# Multiple jQuery .clicks, only use the newest

Tags: jquery

Say I have 2 Javascript files, `includeFirst.js`, and `includeSecond.js`, which are loading into the page. IF the first contains some code like:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
   alert('Hello World');
}
```

And the second contains:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    alert('World Hello');
}
```

I'm getting both alerts popping up. Is there any way I can add something to the .click in the second so that the first doesn't run?

I realize this coding method seems sloppy/bad, but it's just to fix a bit of legacy code that will be fully rewritten soon. I'd just like to fix this temporarily.

Comment: you can remove the click handler using `.off()` - `$('#myButton').off('click').click(function() {
    alert('World Hello');
}`

Comment: there is the `stopImmediatePropagation` method of the event object. add it as the first statement to both of your handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second JS file, use `off()` to remove any existing handlers before attaching the new click event:

```
$('#myButton').off('click').click(function() {
    alert('World Hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Unbind existing event handlers

You should unbind any existing event handlers and then bind a new one. but beware that this may have undesired effects when existing event handlers do something vital and new ones don't replicate this behaviour.

```
$("#myButton")
    .unbind("click")
    .click(function(){
        alert("Hello world");
    });
```

I've chained these calls so it will first unbind any existing *click* event handlers (and **all of them** when there are several) and then bind a new one...

### Unbinding particular event handlers of the same type

If you'd like to unbind only particular event handlers of the same type, you can use [event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). They have the form of `click.namespaceName`

> **jQuery `.bind()` Docs:**
>   If the *eventType* string contains a period (.) character, then the
>   event is namespaced. The period character separates the event from its
>   namespace. For example, in the call `.bind( "click.name", handler)`,
>   the string *click* is the event type, and the string *name* is the
>   namespace. Namespacing allows us to unbind or trigger some events of a
>   type without affecting others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unbind function to remove all the click events that are bound to the element.

```
      var myButton = $("#myButton");
      myButton.unbind('click');
      myButton.click(function() {
          alert('World Hello');
      }
```

NOTE: this code has not been tested.

Answer (score -2):

try using event.preventDefault() in your second click event

Comment: that will only prevent the default behavior...for example, it will prevent anchor tags from navigating to an URL, etc.